# Setting an Angular ng-repeat limit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to setup a limit on my slides, as it stands i have added `data-ng-repeat="job in jobs | limitTo : 10"`i noticing 12 slides are still displaying. Is there something incorrect my code for this function not to work [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

```
 var timer;
$scope.startAuto = function() {
    timer = $interval(function(){
        $scope.jobNotification = ($scope.jobNotification + 1) % $scope.jobs.length;
    }, 5000);
};

$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope.jobNotification === index;

 };

    $scope.showJobNotification = function (index) {
    if (timer){
        $interval.cancel(timer);
        $scope.startAuto();
    }
    $scope.jobNotification = index;
};

$scope.stopAuto = function() {
  console.log('tickCtrl.stopAuto() triggered');
  if(timer) {
  $interval.cancel(timer);
  timer = undefined;        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit the jobNotification value. Reducing the modulo to 10 prevents slide 11 and 12 from ever showing.

`$scope.jobNotification = ($scope.jobNotification + 1) % 10;`